# Google play app submission uploading screenshots from an 8 inch tablet

Tags: android, google-play

This might be a bit off-topic..

When submitting an app on the google play-store, we need screenshots from either 7 or 10 inch tablet so that our apps qualify for "Designed for Tablets" thing..

My question is do we precisely need 7 or 10 inch tablets. What if we have an 8 inch tablet? I am planning to buy one soon and want to ensure that I am able to upload screenshots for my app on the playstore using it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened to me that I wrongly uploaded a 7-inch capture as a 10-inch tablets captures, and there was no error in that.
Actually, tablets range also to other sizes, and recently phablets have extended the concept of tablets and phones.

So, I think that there is not a real control from Google, 7inch and 10inch are as I suppose only two generic groups of captures, where many other devices fall into. The real point is that the developer SHOULD give the exact idea of the user experience before downloading the app.